# Find the lastest qualifying row for each key

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table in my database:

[image]

I want to get 2 columns: `id_chantier` and `id_chef`.
Conditions: `date_fin not null` and has the last `date_deb`.
So the rows that I want to get are number `1` and `11`.
How can I do that?

Comment: and row 8?.. what you mean  "has the last date_deb"?..

Comment: Can you post the query you've currently got, also can you clarify why you want rows 1 and 11, not just 11 (11 has 2015-03-23, which is later than 1's 2015-01-23)?

Comment: Shouldn't that be *only* row 11?  Why is row 1 included?  It would make sense to include 1 if `date_deb` were 2015-03-23.

Comment: i want to get the list of sites (chantier) that are closed (date_fin is not null) and the last worked chief for each site

Comment: Typically, it is better to provide data as text. We cannot copy / paste from an image. And remember to provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_chef)
       id_chantier, id_chef
FROM   tbl
WHERE  date_fin IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY id_chef, date_deb DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Details for `DISTINCT ON`

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Depending on data distribution there may be faster solutions:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Thnx it's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `rank()`:

```
select id_chantier, id_chef
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by date_deb desc) as rnk
      from table t
     ) t
where date_fin is not null and rnk = 1;
```

Comment: I believe that ASC will give the output he listed as expected

Comment: @sidux . . . The question asks for the last `date_deb`.

Comment: question - yes, but the expected output - no.

Answer (score 0):

-- I want to get the list of sites (chantier) that are closed (date_fin is not null)

```
SELECT *
FROM ztable t
WHERE date_fin IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ztable nx
    WHERE nx.id_chantier = t.id_chantier -- Same site
    AND nx.date_fin > t.date_fin         -- more recent
    );
```